# How can I delete this wordpress category? It's seems indelible

Tags: wordpress

[I want to delete this "Kisisel Gelisim" category but I couldn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqDvw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the "uncategorized" term in the categories.
You cannot delete it, because posts with no category set will belong to this.

But you can change the standard category. Go in Wordpress Backend to "Settings" -> "Writing" -> "Default Post Category" and choose a category term which you do not want to delete.

After that, you are able to delete your "Kisisel Gelisim"

Comment: Hi, I deleted 47 content which is belong to "kisisel gelisim". They were on the trash, but now there is no post belong to that category but still it can't be deleted.